# Import certificate to Certificate Manager (beta) on IBM-Cloud with REST Post function

Tags: rest, post, certificate, ibm-cloud, ibm-certificate-manager

I'm trying to import a certificate to my Certificate Manager service on IBM-Cloud. I always get this response 
`{ "code": "CRTERR400-01", "message": "There is something wrong with the content of your certificate" }` The body of JSON looks like this -> `{ "name": "string", "data": { "content": "" } }`

In content I put date from certificate .pem file which I already import to certificate manager via ibm-cloud Webpage. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of certificate being imported should only contain the PEM format string (from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- to -----END CERTIFICATE-----, including) where all line breaks are replaced by `\n`.

So, a sample body JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "name":"My Certificate",
    "data": {
                "content":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nGQYgv6Nvbwmka2t1Y1k=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    }
}
```